# Compiling legacy software with gcc-5 - make system cannot find libgfortranbegin.a - but I can

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, legacy-code, root-framework

I am trying to compile some legacy software. (CERN Root 5.34)

In order to do this, I needed to install gcc-5, as I encountered errors with the latest version of gcc.

(Using gcc-5 is just a guess. I am fairly confident this should be a "ok" version to use.)

Root compiles with a configure / make system.

My system is debian 9 stretch. In order not to break my system, and to install multiple versions of gcc simultaneously, I followed the info here:

https://gcc.gnu.org/faq.html#multiple

I chose the prefix: `--prefix=/home/user/Programs`

I compiled gcc with no issues, and ran `make install`.

I can see for example the file `/home/user/Programs/bin/g++`

```
/home/user/Programs/bin/g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 5.5.0
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I ran into a problem when building root.

The error I encounter is

```
make CC=/home/user/Programs/bin/gcc CXX=/home/user/Programs/bin/g++
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libminicern.so -m64 -O2 -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--as-needed -o lib/libminicern.so misc/minicern/src/cernlib.o -ldl misc/minicern/src/kernlib.o misc/minicern/src/zebra.o misc/minicern/src/hbook.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/libgfortran.so libgfortranbegin.a
g++: error: libgfortranbegin.a: No such file or directory
/home/ecb/directory/root/misc/minicern/Module.mk:48: recipe for target 'lib/libminicern.so' failed
```

As you can see I have specified make to use the gcc-5 C and C++ compilers.

I have found 2 versions of `libgfortranbegin.a` on my system. One is at `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6` and the other is at `~/Programs/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.5.0`.

I thought it was a bit weird that the path was "unknown-linux" so I made the symlink `~/Programs/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.5.0` - this didn't fix the issue however.

I tried to search for info on this, but I only found one hit

https://root-forum.cern.ch/t/cant-find-libgfortranbegin-a-when-installing-root-6-06-04/21222

I don't think this is particularly relevant - not only is a different (major) version of the software used, with a different (major) version of the compiler, but in addition this person had issues with `make install` I can't even get past `make`.

One thing that I noted reading about was when building gcc-5, I *was not* supposed to specify an option to change where the general C and C++ includes and libs are placed. I do not fully understand what the consequences of this are... Do the gcc-5 related `include` and `lib...` directories get placed relative to `--prefix=/home/user/Programs`?

If I look inside `/home/user/Programs` I have directories such as `bin`, `lib`, `lib32`, `lib64` `include` - so this suggests the answer to the above question is "Yes" and therefore this is not the cause of the problem.

I no longer have any further ideas of how to proceed with this. I know where `libgfortranbegin.a` is - at least 2 versions are installed, one for the default system wide one for gcc6 and one for my local gcc-5 install.

Do I need to tell make or configure where to find `libgfortranbegin.a`? If so how do I do this?

Comment: I find it easiest to setup a VM with the older version of the compiler. For example, I still test with GCC 3. I use a Fedora 1 in a VM so I don't have to waste time with building compilers and configuring installations.

Comment: @jww Yeah, that sounds a reasonable course of action to investigate about the problem.

Comment: Started working on this before realising it does not work. Debian 9 doesn't seem to have either gcc-4 or gcc-5 in repos. This means I have to build it from source. That means I have to put a local prefix to install it or I may break my system https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian

Comment: Any chance you can upgrade to a current version of ROOT, instead of investing +/- the same time in resurrecting an old one? Folks at https://root-forum.cern.ch will be happy to help...

Comment: @AxelNaumann No I can't - I am trying to install legacy software which (probably) requires a root 5 version. It will not work with root 6